# Storing elements from a database column in a string array VB.NET - program crashes

Tags: vb.net

Hi I am writing a program that reads all the rows (elements) in a column of a database and outputs each element into a string array. The program should collect the string values for 'Student Results' and put them into the 'SubjectGrade' array. The problem is that when getting the data using a For Loop, the program just crashes and does not proceed. I am store the data in a one dimensional array so I just specified the item number as '4' being the last column in the table.
Does anyone have any I ideas how I might be able to fix this problem and successfully store the data in the array?

Thanks.

Ben.

Code Below:

```
Public Class FormViewingOptionsMassGrade
    Public NumberOfRows As Integer
    Public SubjectGrade(NumberOfRows) As String

 Public Function FormViewingOptionsMassGrade_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'StudentResults_DatabaseDataSet.Student_Results' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        'StudentResultsDataGridView.Hide()
        Me.Student_ResultsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StudentResults_DatabaseDataSet.Student_Results)
        NumberOfRows = StudentResultsDataGridView.Rows.GetLastRow(DataGridViewElementStates.None) 'LastRow = 400 in this case.

        ReDim SubjectGrade(NumberOfRows)
        For i As Integer = 0 To NumberOfRows '400
            SubjectGrade(i) = Me.Student_ResultsTableAdapter.GetData.Rows(i).Item(4)
        Next


        Return SubjectGrade(NumberOfRows)
    End Function
```

Comment: Question: How many times will your For loop iterate? Answer: 401

Comment: Also, instead of stating the program "just crashes" please post the text of the exception.

Comment: Also, you are trying to "return" an array of strings from an event handler, and while it is a function, it is not designed to return an array of strings. What are you returning the data to, since the system itself will call the event handler....

Answer (score -2):

```
Public Function FormViewingOptionsMassGrade_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'StudentResults_DatabaseDataSet.Student_Results' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    'StudentResultsDataGridView.Hide()
        Me.Student_ResultsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StudentResults_DatabaseDataSet.Student_Results)
    NumberOfRows = StudentResultsDataGridView.Rows.GetLastRow(DataGridViewElementStates.None) 'LastRow = 400 in this case.

    ReDim SubjectGrade(NumberOfRows)
    For i As Integer = 0 To NumberOfRows '400
        SubjectGrade(i) = Me.Student_ResultsTableAdapter.GetData.Rows(i).Item(4)
    Next

    Return SubjectGrade(NumberOfRows)
End Function
```